# eventmachine.watch_file returns a wrong file state

Tags: eventmachine, dashing

I am following the example: https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/issues/78#issuecomment-14940695

The eventmachine.watch_file returns "file_deleted" everytime I modify the spreadsheet. It should actually return "file_modified"

Can someone help me?

```
require 'roo'

EM.kqueue = EM.kqueue?
file_path = "#{Dir.pwd}/spreadsheet.xls"

def fetch_spreadsheet_data(path)
  s = Roo::Excel.new(path)
  send_event('career_score',   { current: s.cell(2, 2) })
end

module Handler
  def file_modified
    puts "BLAHBLAH1"
    fetch_spreadsheet_data(path)
    puts "BLAHBLAH"
  end
  def file_moved
    puts "Moved"
    fetch_spreadsheet_data(path)
  end
  def file_deleted
    puts "Deleted"
    fetch_spreadsheet_data(path)
  end  
  def unbind
    puts "#{path} monitoring ceased"
  end
end


    fetch_spreadsheet_data(file_path)


    EM.next_tick do
          EM.watch_file(file_path, Handler)
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that roo has problem with XLS files. Works fine after I convert it to CSV.